# Upgrading glibc - How does it work without distribution's patches

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glibc

The Fedora 21 repository has glibc-2.20-8.fc21

I want to install glibc 2.21 from source.  (I realize we're days away from Fedora 22 release, but this question will apply next time I'm interested in installing a more recent version of glibc.)

Running configure on the 2.21 source says:

```
On GNU/Linux systems the GNU C Library should not be installed into
/usr/local since this might make your system totally unusable.
```

It references to see the glibc faq, which then says:

```
The GNU C compiler treats /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib in a special
way, these directories will be searched before the system directories. Since
on GNU/Linux the system directories /usr/include and /usr/lib contain a ---
possibly different --- version of glibc and mixing certain files from
different glibc installations is not supported and will break, you risk
breaking your complete system. If you want to test a glibc installation, use
another directory as argument to --prefix. If you like to install this glibc
version as default version, overriding the existing one, use --prefix=/usr
and everything will go in the right places.
```

I'm debating which way I want to go (a separate directory other than /usr/local, or overriding in /usr).

But, I noticed somewhere that said if you're going to do this, you want to make sure to use the same configure options your linux distribution used.

So, I downloaded glibc-2.20-8.fc21.src.rpm and extracted it.  For the first time, I've seen what the linux distributions are doing to the upstream code.  There's 48 .patch files, 3 extra .c files, an extra .h file, and some .conf files.

Is it (and if so, how is it) safe to ever install glibc from source, regardless of if you're using a second (non /usr/local) location or overwriting in /usr?

All those patches the RedHat/Fedora repository "people" have made are going to be skipped.  (I assume these distribution-specific patches are important...) How are so many places saying upgrading glibc is generally safe?

For that matter, if many distribution packages have this amount of distribution customization, how does building anything from source even work?  I've been running trunk source builds of gcc and gdb for a long time, and occasionally run into bumps because it isn't release code, but it generally works... I don't get how those work now, either, without the distribution repository patches.

Answer (score -1):

upgrading Glibc is not safe. because many of your programs are linked against current version of glibc and upgrading CAN break them. unless you apply patches from your distro. but again I don't recommend that.
you can however use another glibc if you compile your programs static or for example use a bash script to change LD_LIBRARY_PATH when you want to run that application.

in bash:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/new/lib program
```

the best way is to use your current glib to make any program.

thanks to @rubenvb for helping me fix the answer.

Comment: glibc is immensely backwards compatible. Upgrading will definitely not break anything. What breaks stuff is the distribution specific patches and options which you have to replicate in your personally built version. Static linking to glibc is strongly recommended against as well.

Comment: thanks @rubenvb . I think my answer was misleading. I fixed that.

Comment: @rubenvb, so you do have to bring in the distribution specific patches and options, then... Is it pretty much unpack the srpm, drop in the new version .tar, try compiling, and hoping?

Comment: @user1902689 compiling Glibc is really a headache. sometimes you will have to forget some optimization to be able to compile it. and as a recommendation: make sure to carefully run tests/checks before installing it.

Comment: @user1902689 That's how I would do it yes. That's your best bet in any case. As an alternative, check if your distribution has a development branch for packages (for e.g. a new release) that may already include a testing version of the glibc srpm.